# How easy is it to get from Midway (MDW) to downtown Chicago via the L?

Tags: public-transport

I am looking to get to the board of trade from Midway. I have gotten downtown from ORD via the blue line but is MDW as easy?

Comment: Google Maps gives some [pretty clear directions](http://bit.ly/1QD4Mzo). You can get there directly on the orange line and walk about a half mile or transfer if you want the least possible walking. The L station is connected to the Midway terminal and [there are signs](http://www.transitchicago.com/airports/#mdw) to guide you.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. "Easy" is opinion-based; we cannot go out and measure the trip and tell you "Midway to the Loop is 14 standard easiness units, as opposed to O'Hare which is 17." Can you flesh out what specifically you are concerned about— ticket purchase? Headways? Luggage facilities? CTA has [a whole page on airport transfers](http://www.transitchicago.com/airports/#mdw).

Answer (score 2):

The L is right there. So you can take the orange line or blue line into downtown. Ask one of the CTA people working there. Their usually pretty good with giving advice on exactly where you're going.